# Polite “Payment Confirmed” Image

Tags: icon

I'm creating a step-by-step image chart to a website describing a paid program that only liberates access when user's payment is confirmed. I want to be far from showing users some greedy icon (like a sack with a dollar sign) or limiting their idea of payment forms.

My question is: How do you politely show "as soon as your payment is confirmed"? I've thinking about bills/coins/credit card with a green check sign to say everything's right. But I've seen websites using something as simple as a green seal with a white check.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey Patrick, what ideas have you tried? We could probably help a little more then, off the top of my head I guess a cash register icon with a tick or transaction complete or something...?

Comment: @Jenna I've tried some gold coin with a tick and a dollar bill with a tick. But I don't know if it's not too agressive to show users. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I guess it depends on the style of the graphic, if it's a bold stamp coin with a tick it might look a little more aggressive than a more flat design icon. Could you add some screenshots to your question and we could give you feedback on your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, *Payment Confirmed* step is a final step in your image chart. If you're looking for something completely neutral for this task, I suggest to use a simple ***checkmark*** aka *Finished/Done*. I don't see reason why you absolutely must use money imagery for this. Another alternative ***thumbs up*** aka *Approved*.

Second option is to go for *Access Granted* icon. Something with an ***open padlock*** or ***keys***.

Comment: Great idea noirboi, the Access Granted was exactly what I was looking for!